# Simple Math Extraction using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I want to Extract 
-5x^-2
to

-5

x

^

-2

i try to use this

```
var strlist = Regex.Matches(str, @"[+-]?\d+|\D+")
             .Cast<Match>()
             .Select(m => m.Value)
             .ToList();
```

the result is

-5

x^-

2

Comment: You need [reverse polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation).

Answer (score 2):

Using regular expressions to parse a mathematical expression tree is bound to give you a head-ache!

Just write a parser by hand and parse the expression into a tree.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions aren't really good for this kind of work. What you probably need is an arithmetic parser like this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/274093/Math-Parser-NET